# Dirichlet Product - identities

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

Does anyone know of a good resource that shows how the number theoretic functions and their Dirichlet Products are related? This is for further reading but might come in useful for my exams.

I am particularly interested in: $u(n), N(n), \tau(n), \sigma(n), \psi(n), \mu(n)$ and $I(n)$.

For example, I have been looking at the Dirichlet Product of various number theoretic functions with $u(n)$ and have derived the following results:

$(u * u)(n) = \sum_{d|n}u(d)u(n/d) = \sum_{d|n}1 = \tau(n)$

$(N*u)(n)=\sum_{d|n}N(d)u(n/d)=\sum_{d|n}d = \sigma(n)$

$(\psi*u)(n) = \sum_{d|n}\psi(d)u(n/d) = \sum_{d|n}\psi(d) = N(n)$

$(\mu*u)(n) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d)u(n/d) = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d) = I(n)$

I'd be interested to hear about more of these functions and how they are related through the Dirichlet Product.

Answer (score 0):

A "good resource" here is the book [Introduction to Analytic Number Theory](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387901633) by Tom Apostol. This will be very useful. Chapter $2$ is about Arithmetical Functions and Dirichlet Multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look.